Sunglasses damaged by lake water?
I was recently fly fishing at a local lake in Denver, CO.  I always wear polarized sunglasses while fishing.  I've fished with these sunglasses before at this lake and elsewhere with no issues, but this time it was super windy.  Each time I caught a fish (rainbow trout) there was a lot of splashing and the wind blew the water into my face and onto my sunglasses.  I figured the water would naturally evaporate or I could clean off the glasses later so I didn't do much at the time.  When I left and took off my sunglasses (Goodr “I do my own stunts”) I noticed that the mirror finish on the lenses was trashed.  There were droplet and spray patterns etched into the finish and dark spots where it was completely gone.

My theory is that the lake water has an abnormal pH or something and the water reacted with the reflective coating on the glasses causing it to erode away. I can neither confirm or deny this.

Anyone know what happened?
Is this a normal thing for sunglasses?
How would I prevent this from happening in the future? i.e., clean off sunglasses right away, OR pre-apply some kind of water-repellent coating to the sunglasses, OR purchase sunglasses that have a 'water repellent' feature (if that even exists)?


Water drops concentrate sunlight, can it be the protection layer is burned in those places?

This happened to me when I had my glasses up on my head and I was rained on. A bit annoying, but they weren't super expensive glasses so I just bought new ones.

This might well be unanswerable here, unless you can supply the model and make of your glasses. There may be some care instructions in a manual.

"How would I prevent this from happening in the future?" I suggest you buy glasses with polarized lenses, not the cheap kind with a coating. Bin them, and spend a bit more.

This happened to me once with a pair of Goodr sunglasses my first day raft guiding with them. I've never had a problem with more expensive sunglasses (for ex my prescription ones). My current go-to brand for cheap-ish but still functional sunglasses is Blenders (not sponsored, just use them on the river). These for example seem like a similar style to what you have but I can't speak to this model specifically. I use the "victory lane": https://www.backcountry.com/blenders-eyewear-expose-polarized-sunglasses?skid=BEW002T-FORGINPOL-ONESIZ

Yep these are polarized and I’ve added the brand and model. I guess I should have just been more proactive about cleaning them off right away.

Did you spray insect repellant near them? DEET is not kind to many synthetic materials...

"Victory Lane" sit a little too far off the face for me, I want a pretty tight wrap. Thanks for the suggestion.  I had not sprayed any insect repellant near them, it was purely water.

Prevention Tips
Immediate Cleaning: Always clean your sunglasses immediately after exposure to water, especially if it’s splashed or if you notice residue. Use a microfiber cloth and appropriate lens cleaner to avoid scratching.
Water-Repellent Coatings: Consider sunglasses that come with built-in hydrophobic or water-repellent coatings. These can help repel water and minimize the risk of spots forming.
Pre-Apply Coatings: Some aftermarket water-repellent sprays can be applied to sunglasses. Ensure they are compatible with your lens material and coatings.
Choose Quality Sunglasses: Invest in high-quality polarized sunglasses with durable coatings that are designed for water sports or fishing. Brands often have specific models designed to withstand harsh conditions.
Store Properly: When not in use, store your sunglasses in a protective case to avoid scratches and damage from environmental factors.
